# doctrine 2 - working with repositories

Tags: doctrine-orm, repository

I would like to start using Doctrine 2 for a new project but I noticed that doctrine now allows to define repositories: http://mackstar.com/blog/2010/10/04/using-repositories-doctrine-2

I'm not sure how to structure my project now because isn't one of the purposes of using repositories that you can switch to another ORM when needed.
So if you use Doctrine repositories, this possibility is gone.

Or should I define my own repositories and in those repositories make use of calls to the doctrine repository? That seems a bit odd...

Comment: Define your own repository interface and only use those methods in your application.  Your Doctrine 2 repository should then implement the interface.  You can keep things simple by having your interface more or less match Doctrine's.  If you decide to switch to a different ORM then just have it's repositories implement the interface.  Your application won't notice.

Comment: Thats a very good point. So should I put everything in a repository? Not only "finding" but also create/update/delete?  Because most tutorials are mixing it up and use repositories only for selecting data and perform saving outside the repository.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should put the creation of new domain objects in a Factory class. This is a dedicated class dedicated to the construction of objects. By calling them as a service, you can decouple the object creation from the client, meaning the client code doesn't need to reference concrete class. You'll also have one place to customise production of new objects. As for repositories, Cerad's solution is sensible. And also bear in mind that you might be over-engineering the problem: the chances of changing out a repository layer once written are slim!

Comment: Yes, create/update/delete methods can go in repositories.  As far as factories go, consider the repository itself to be a factory.  So as @Matt implies. never actually use the new operator on your entities.

Comment: OK, thx Guys, but I don't fully understand why I shouldn't use  "new" to create an object.

Comment: It's hard to explain why in a few sentences.  It will become clearer once you have made a few repos.

Comment: But you are using "new" in your repository?

Comment: Yes, use "new" in your repository/factory. If you use "new" to create Entities in your controllers and so on, it'll be very hard to test your controllers because you won't be able to mock the entities. By having one single place where entities are created and instantiated it also means you can swap out the implementation of the entity for another if you want to at a later date

Comment: Ok thx, I was a little confused, but I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on the comments, this is the base repository class that I use.

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository as BaseRepository;

class EntityRepository extends BaseRepository implements ApplicationRepository
{
    // Create main entity
    public function createEntity($params = array())
    {
        $entityName = $this->getEntityName();
        return new $entityName($params);
    }
    // Allow null for id
    public function find($id)
    {
        return $id ? parent::find($id) : null;
    }
    /* ==========================================================
     * Persistence
     */
    public function persist($entity) { return $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity); }
    public function remove($entity)  { return $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);  }
    public function flush()          { return $this->getEntityManager()->flush();          }
    public function clear()          { return $this->getEntityManager()->clear();          }
}
```

Having the ability to support multiple repository types is actually quite useful.  I'll often implement InMemory repositories which work off of yaml files for initial development and testing.

Comment: thx for the example, I don't fully understand the entity creation. Did you write a constructor that matches the passed array to the class properties?

Comment: Yep but I seldom use it.  Mostly for testing.  Helps to be able to pass in an array of values sometimes.  Get rid of it you like.

Comment: Ok and how do you create the entity without the array? Still in the repository? By passing the values comma separated?

Comment: Nope.  Your objects should not have a constructor at all.  Kind of getting back to the factory thing here.  Maybe update your question and show the constructor for an object or two.